# Appium -this.nativeTap is not a function at XCUITestDriver.navigate

Tags: xcode8, appium-ios

[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: TypeError: this.nativeTap is not a function
    at XCUITestDriver.navigate$ (../../../lib/commands/context.js:411:18)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)

Comment: I would recommend creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example][1] as per Stack Overflow's question guidelines.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue. 
In my case the issue was: in my appium command I have the browser specified. But for Appium version: >= 1.6, Safari is the default Capability, so we do not need to specify it. After removing it, I did not get this error.
My appium command looks like this:

```
appium -p 4444 --command-timeout 600
```